what would happen if the "signal.signal" function call is removed
I have this legacy code and I'd like to add error handling to it. To my surprise, I found that the try and except did not work in it. After some debug, turns out it was because of the signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN) code that made the main process to ignore the child exceptions. So in the original code, except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e: would never be reached. I doubt if this was done correctly by the previous programmer and I'd like to remove the signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN) line so that the try...except would work as expected. But I don't know if this would cause any trouble in handling the child process.(for example, zombie child process that I'm not aware of being created). Any suggestions on how to modify it?
import threading
import logging
import queue
import subprocess
import signal



class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, thread_id, work_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._thread_id = thread_id
        self._queue = work_queue

    def run(self):
        while not self._queue.empty():
            module = self._queue.get()
            os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = str(self._thread_id)
            try:
                subprocess.check_output(["python3.8", module])
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
                logging.error(
                    "Worker: {} failed to process '{}'. Error: {}".format(
                        self._thread_id,
                        module.split("/")[-1], e))
            self._queue.task_done()
        logging.info("Worker: {} has exited!".format(self._thread_id))


def process_modules(modules):
    modulesQueue = queue.Queue()
    for i in modules:
        modulesQueue.put(i)

    workers = []
    gpu_allocator = BaseGPUAllocator()
    for i in range(gpu_allocator.avail_gpu_card_number()):
        worker = Worker(i,
                        modulesQueue)  # create a worker for each available GPU
        workers.append(worker)
        worker.start()  # start the worker
    modulesQueue.join()  # wait for all modules to be processed


def validate_models():
    modules = ["case1", "case2"]
    process_modules(modules)
    return modules


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Ignore SIGCHLD handler to not creating zombie child processes.
    signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN)

    validate_models()


You have far more issues here than just the question about signals. Looks like the original programmer didn't quite grasp how threading can be achieved and managed in Python. for i in range(1) is particularly intriguing. There's no need for a queue

@SIGHUP I'm very new to multithreading in python, could you elaborate a little more?

Take a look at this documentation and, in particular, the ThreadPoolExecutor for a much simpler implementation of your code's functionality

@SIGHUP if I simply remove the signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN) line in the above code, what could possibly happen? Will it get stuck?

There is no need for any signal handling here. There's also no need for a queue. It's just overcomplicated. Here's some code that achieves the same functionality in just a few lines:
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import logging
import subprocess

PYTHON = "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3"

def process(module):
    try:
        subprocess.run([PYTHON, module], check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        logging.error(f"Module {module} failed due to {e}")

def main():
    modules = ["module1.py", "module2.py"]
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as exe:
        exe.map(process, modules)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The only potential issue here is if the called "module" gets stuck. You'd have to write some rather elaborate code to manage that eventuality

In the original code, it tried to use all the GPU in the machine(for example, if it has 4 gpu, it would create 4 workers). That's why it was using a queue, to handle task balance between the workers.

It doesn't work like that. Also, there's nothing in standard multithreading or multiprocessing that will take advantage of GPUs. If you want to take advantage of multiple CPUs you should be multiprocessing - not multithreading. If you want to change the code in this answer to use multiprocessing just import ProcessPoolExecutor which has the same signature as ThreadPoolExecutor and can therefore just be "dropped in"

I've added the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES related code to the posted code. This was how it was done in the past and it has been working just fine. It indeed utilized all 4 gpus on the machine.
